# Complete local ring which is not complete valuation ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, valuation-theory

Complete valuation ring is obviously complete local, because valuation ring is always local ring.

I would like to know the example of

> Complete local ring which is not complete valuation ring

Any examples? I could find example of local ring which is not valuation ring, but the example ring is not complete.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please, provide a definition of complete local ring. How do you define completeness without using the concept of valuation on a ring?

Comment: [DaRT query](http://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/search/results/?H=1&H=143&L=154l) for complete local rings that are not valuation domains.

Comment: @Crostul It seems that one way is "a local ring in which the canonical map into the completion at the maximal ideal is an isomorphism." but of course it would be best to see what the poster has to say about it...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- $k[x]/(x^2)$ is a complete local ring, it is not a valuation ring because it is not an integral domain.
- $R=k[[x^2,x^3]]$ is a local ring, it is complete because $R\to \underset{n\to \infty}\varprojlim R/\mathfrak{m}^n$ is an isomorphism, it is not a valuation ring because $x,x^{-1}\in Frac(R),\not \in R$.

  Equivalently its principal ideals are not totally ordered: $(x^3)\not\subset (x^2)$, $(x^2)\not\subset (x^3)$.
- The completion at the maximal ideal doesn't have to be the same as the completion for the valuation: $S= \{ \sum_{j\ge 1} c_j x^{b_j},c_j\in k, b_j\in \Bbb{Q}_{\ge 0}, \lim_{j\to \infty} b_j=\infty\}$, then $\mathfrak{m}^n = \mathfrak{m}$ so $\underset{n\to \infty}\varprojlim S/\mathfrak{m}^n=S/\mathfrak{m}\cong k$ while $S$ is complete for the valuation (every Cauchy sequence converges in $S$).