# Complete ring which is not integral domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Is every complete ring $R$ with respect to some ideal $I$ integral domain?

I heard somewhere completion of a ring is motivated to eliminate torsion elements.

I'd like to know,Is every complete ring $R$ an integral domain?

If there are some counterexamples,I'd like to know that.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Shoulda tried the [DaRT query](https://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/search/results/?H=1&H=143&L=8)

Comment: So let me get this straight, you asked a question five days ago which was answered the same day [containing an example of such a ring](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4044132/29335) and now you’re asking again today? One begins to wonder if you’re reading responses at all...